# Difference between Color.colorName and Color(.colorName)

Tags: xcode, swiftui

The blue color produced by `Color.blue` is different from the one produced by `Color(.blue)`. Is this a bug in Xcode preview, or do they really present different values? This doesn't apply to blue only but to several colors such as "red".
[image: Screenshot of xcode showing the color difference]

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? The latter Color initializer is deprecated with iOS 16.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the two are different. By command-clicking on the tokens and using Xcode's "Jump to definition" feature, you can see the headers where they are defined.

For `Color.blue`:

```
extension Color {
// ...
/// A context-dependent blue color suitable for use in UI elements.
public static let blue: Color
```

For `Color(.blue)`:

```
open class UIColor {
// ...
open class var blue: UIColor { get } // 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 RGB
```

Note that `Color.blue` says "context-dependent" -- this will change with various system environments, such as light or dark mode.

Also relevant: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/standard_colors

Also see note in the comments about a deprecation warning.

Comment: I was just getting ready to post the same. The ability to use `Color(.blue)` is deprecated now (as of iOS 16.2) and has been replaced with `Color(uiColor: .blue)` or `Color(nsColor: .blue)`.